# Is there a way of getting a UITextField's text updates in a declarative way?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am confused why this following code does not work.

```
dateTextField.publisher(for: \.text)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion  in
        print("completion", completion)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("value", value ?? "")
    }).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

I just receive the first event, of an empty text. My guess is because UITextField's text property is not KVO-compliant. But, why does the subscription receive the first value?

Answer (score 1):

You can now listen to NotificationCenter updates

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: yourTextField).map { ($0.object as! UITextField).text }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how and where (which run-time env) you use it, but it works. Tested with Xcode 11.2/Swift 5.1/iOS 13.2

Here is the demo of testing UITextField publisher from SwiftUI (just attached publisher to existed test and it works). Hope it helps somehow.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    private let cancelable: AnyCancellable
    private let myTextView: UITextView

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
        myTextView = UITextView()

        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
        myTextView.isEditable = true
        myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cancelable = myTextView.publisher(for: \.text)
            .sink { value in
                print("Get: \(value ?? "no value")")
            }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        self.myTextView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return self.myTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView

        init(_ uiTextView: TextView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
}

struct TestTextViewNewLine: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Label:")
            TextView(text: $text)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke())
                .frame(maxHeight: 32)
        }
    }
}

struct TestTextViewNewLine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestTextViewNewLine()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2019-11-21 21:59:10.436516+0200 Test[1122:35207] [Agent] Received display message
Get: 
Get: 
Get: H
Get: He
Get: Hel
Get: Hell
Get: Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and apparently there's a clear reason for this: my controller was deallocated. So I suggest checking both the subscription and the object owning it